# How to make function call other like callback

Tags: visual-c++

Heres what I want (image):

[image]

Main Idea is:
InputField is a function that calls something if input value changed.
For example: you have text input field in game and you add text to it, when value doesnt change until like 1 second it will call code like g_Engine.ChangeName()

Heres also callback class, but I dont know how to do it still please help

Code:

```
typedef void (*fn_callback)(void);
class pCallback
{
public:
    pCallback(fn_callback callback);
    fn_callback callback_void{ nullptr };
};

class CMenu
{
private:
    void InputField(int x, int y, char* text, int maxLen, int& out, ...);
};

extern CMenu g_Menu;

void CMenu::InputField(int x, int y, char* text, int maxLen, int& out, ...)
{
    unsigned int w = 220;
    unsigned int h = 16;

    g_pISurface->DrawSetColor(cvar.cheat_global_color_r, cvar.cheat_global_color_g, cvar.cheat_global_color_b, 255);
    g_pISurface->DrawOutlinedRect(x - 2, y - 2, x + w + 2, y + h + 2);

    bool clicked = false;

    static DWORD dwTemporaryBlockTimer = 0;

    static std::string value;

    if (GetTickCount() - dwPaletteBlockedTime > 200 && GetTickCount() - dwListBlockedTime > 200 && !bCursorInPalette && !bCursorInList && keys[VK_LBUTTON] && !IsDragging && CursorX >= x && CursorX <= x + w && CursorY >= y && CursorY <= y + h)
    {
        if (GetTickCount() - dwTemporaryBlockTimer > 200)
        {
            clicked = true;
            dwTemporaryBlockTimer = GetTickCount();
        }
    }

    if (clicked || CursorX >= x && CursorX <= x + w && CursorY >= y && CursorY <= y + h)
    {
        g_pISurface->DrawSetColor(cvar.cheat_global_color_r, cvar.cheat_global_color_g, cvar.cheat_global_color_b, 255);
        g_pISurface->DrawOutlinedRect(x - 1, y - 1, x + w + 1, y + h + 1);
    }

    if (text)
        g_Drawing.DrawString(MENU, x + 1, y - 10, 215, 215, 215, 255, FONT_LEFT, text);

    
    if (GetTickCount() - dwInputfieldBlockedTime > 200 && !bCursorInPalette && !bCursorInList && !IsDragging && CursorX >= x && CursorX <= x + w && CursorY >= y && CursorY <= y + h)
    {
        if (maxLen != 0)
        {
            if (!(value.length() > maxLen))
                value.append(GetPressedNumKeyString());
        }

        if (keys[VK_BACK])
        {
            if (!value.empty())
                value.erase(std::prev(value.end()));
        }

        dwInputfieldBlockedTime = GetTickCount();
    }

    int iVal = std::atoi(value.c_str());

    if (out != iVal)
        out = iVal;

    if (!value.empty())
        g_Drawing.DrawString(MENU, x + w / 2, y + (h / 2), 220, 220, 220, 255, FONT_CENTER, value.c_str());
    else
        g_Drawing.DrawString(MENU, x + w / 2, y + (h / 2), 81, 81, 81, 255, FONT_CENTER, "N/A");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it

```
void CMenu::InputField(int x, int y, char* text, int maxLen, int& out, std::function<void()>&& Callback)
{
    if (out != iVal)
    {
        out = iVal;
        Callback();
    }
}

InputField(x + box_indent_x, y + line_y, "SteamID", 31, SID, []() { g_SteamID.Apply(SID); });
```